# Append file to json in client and get in api server in php

Tags: php, json, file-upload

I am trying to send file and some other data by cruel to API . i want to appended data to JSON file and send.
I can do it but in server i can not get uploaded file.
When i don't use format JSON i have not any problem that i access to $_file but in JSON I have not any file i have some data string only

client:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'submit') {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

        $filePath = $_FILES['file_upl']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['file_upl']['type'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['file_upl']['name'];
        echo "filePath::" . $filePath;
        echo "<br>fileName:" . $fileName;
         $data = (['name' => 'Foo', 'file_upl' => curl_file_create($filePath, $type, $fileName)] );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $data ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo "<br>result: " . $result;
    }
}?>
<form name="file_up" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload your file here
    <input type="file" name="file_upl" id="file_upl"/>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

serve:

```
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        echo "<pre>";
        echo 'in web SErvice: <br/>';
        echo (print_r($data));
        echo (print_r( $data->)); 
        echo $data->file_upl->name;
        echo $data->file_upl->tmp_name;

move_uploaded_file($data->file_upl->name, Yii::app()->basePath . "/files/" . $data->file_upl->postname);
```

result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => Foo
    [file_upl] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php8843.tmp
                    [mime] => image/jpeg
                    [postname] => 1-7.jpg
```

it is important for me that use JSON format. please tell me how can use std Class Object in to method move_uploaded_file that can be get file.

Comment: What do you mean "by cruel"?

Comment: This makes no sense at all. I can't figure out what you're trying to do. And I have no idea what this means: "how can use std Class Object in to method move_uploaded_file that can be get file"... just sounds like a random jumble of words.

Comment: @geoidesic, I'm sorry my English is not good.In summary, I want my web service to work with a  post method get a data of the file type. And upload  in an path. but i can not do it . because i use json format to transfer data.

Comment: @geoidesic, I have a question: Is a file, for example, a picture can be placed as a data in the Jason file and used on web services?
If possible, how should it be placed in the method move_uploaded_file().  my mail : masoudy.maryam@gmail.com  If you help me, I'm grateful to you

Comment: Your English is very confusing. I can't tell what you are asking because the way you ask it could mean an array of different things. However it sounds like you are asking how to upload a file using PHP. This is very basic stuff that you can get from Google, e.g.: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp